# Adding cookie header causes request to hang

Tags: php

I'm working on a class project where we need to make use of php to write a website. We're told that we should write separate pages that we query for information along with a php session for keeping variables. I have successfully gotten a session started but when I try to make a request and I add a header for the session, the request stalls and doesn't complete. Below is the code that I'm using.

```
function GetDataV2(string $URL, string $method, array $postPayload)
{
    $sessID = $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'];
    $cookieString = "Cookie: PHPSESSID=$sessID";

    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header' => array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Accept: application/json', $cookieString),
            'method' => 'POST',       
            'content' => http_build_query($postPayload)
        )
    );

    $context = stream_context_create($options);

    return file_get_contents($URL, false, $context);
}
```

Any help is appreciated since I cannot seem to figure out what is causing the request to just hang. Unfortunately php is required for the project otherwise I wouldn't use it at all.

Answer (score 0):

After doing more extensive searching, I needed to add session_write_close() before executing the call to release the session file before the other page could modify it.